# ActionBarActivity и просто Activity, в чем разница?

Tags: android, activity

ActionBarActivity и просто Activity, в чем разница?

Answer (score 2):

> Base class for activities that use the support library action bar features.
>
> You can add an ActionBar to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending this class for your activity and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme.

[developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html)

Исчерпывающе, по-моему

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar это элемент интерфейса, по сути, его можно добавить в активити и описать полностью